# Form field required despite setting required attr to false

Tags: django, django-forms

I've managed to do something really strange.  I have a web app in Django (2.1, 
 also using Bootstrap, jQuery) that is misbehaving.

In my forms.py, I have defined:

```
caption = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        'required': False, 'class': "roll-caption", 'placeholder': "Caption",
    }
))
```

In the model.py,

```
caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

The class and placeholder render just fine.  I've covered every base I can think of.  But, the form field is being rendered as required in html.  Needless to say, I am confused.  The form field is sitting inside of some divs, but that shouldn't affect it, I thought.

Any idea what I've managed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `required=False` to the form field itself. Please take a look at [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#required).
Your code should look like

```
caption = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=...)
```